# GNU C basic asm stack push before function call caused different behavior on Mac and Linux

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm writing a tiny compiler on x86 platform. When I was testing inline assembly code on Linux and mac OS, I found this code slice has different behaviors on these two platforms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void ret() {
    std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    asm volatile ("sub $0x08, %rsp"); // on linux okay, but on macOS will SIGSEGV. After changing it to `asm volatile ("sub $0x10, %rsp");`, macOS platform behaves well.
    asm volatile ("mov %r15, 0x0(%rsp)");
    asm volatile ("mov %0, %%r10"::"r"((void*)ret));
    asm volatile ("call *%r10");
    asm volatile ("int $0x03");
}
```

It faults before reaching the `int3` software breakpoint.

I want to save(push) an r15 register in order to save it(though I know it is a callee saved register), and I didn't think the `sub $0x08, %rsp` has anything wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: All of this is totally unsafe; you modify registers without telling the compiler about it!!!  Including even the stack pointer!  **It's surprising it works anywhere without segfaulting when `main` returns.**  (I assume you must have compiled with optimization disabled, so maybe `main` restored RSP from RBP before returning.)  You're using GNU C Basic Asm, not Extended.  Plus, this will clobber the red-zone below RSP, where the compiler could be keeping locals.  And also, you put each instruction in a separate statement, so there's no guarantee that the compiler didn't put code between them.

Comment: This is not a valid use of inline assembly.  Behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Maybe the compiler you used on OS X used `leave` instead of just `pop %rbp` at the bottom of `main`. Or maybe you faulted because of incorrect stack alignment when making a function call.  You can't know whether compiler-generated code will do an odd or even number of `push` instructions before your code, so you don't know whether to `sub` `16*n + 0` or `16*n + 8` to restore 16-byte alignment. If the implementation of `ostream::operator<<` happens to assume that its stack is 16-byte aligned and uses `movaps` to copy 16 bytes, that can crash. (e.g. modern Linux glibc scanf will crash like that)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I get it :)  By the way, I use an `int 3` call to simply break the return of main. I think the reason is the `movaps` or similar instructions because I set the `0x08` to `0x18`, `0x28` etc. and it booms; but when setting to `0x10` or `0x20` etc. it goes well.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying `main` segfaults *before* reaching your software breakpoint.  That wasn't in the question.  Yeah, alignment is the most likely reason.  All functions are *allowed* to segfault if you call them with a misaligned stack, and some actually do in practice, depending on the system and how libc was compiled.

Comment: @PeterCordes I get it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wonder why you don't just put your assembly code into an assembly source file.  Works find this way.

Comment: @fuz Because I'm writing a tiny compiler and, the machine code I emit will call a c++ function and then I get a SIGSEGV. So I write inline asm code and call a c++ function in order to reproduce the problem:)

Comment: @wind2412 I see why you write ASM code.  But you could write the same ASM code in an assembly source file and it would be much easier to debug because you can avoid all the uncertainty about stack layouts etc. you have when you use inline assembly.

Comment: @fuz You are right. I will use it. Thank you!